# Как повесить несколько функций на одну кнопку?

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть две функции (три, пять и т.п.) и кнопка на которую нужно их повесить. Нужно чтобы по однократному нажатию на эту кнопку выполнялась первая функция и вторая.
попробовал на кнопке прописать скрипты через знаки  "," ";" "." "&" "&&" "+" - не принимает.
По отдельности работает, вместе не работает. Выдает сообщение "Скриптовая функция function1 **+** function2 не найдена"
Собственно вопрос: как же это делается?
Или нужно в скрипте все наваливать под одну ф-цию?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Одна кнопка - одна функция. Можете создать функцию, которая вызывает все ваши другие функции и ее указать на кнопке

Comment: @Prianichkin Sergey Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Что вам мешает из функции кнопки вызвать другие функции?

Функция кнопки

```js
function userAction(){
  function1();
  function2();
}
```